# C++ Boost ptr_map with const value

Tags: c++, boost

I am working on an existing project and I am trying to replace a
`std::map<AClass,const *BCLass>` with a `boost::ptr_map<AClass,const BClass>`. The problem is that I can't find a way to insert a pair  into the map. Seems that all the insert function can't accept a const value. There's a solution to that? I've also tried with the boost::assign::ptr_map_insert() with no luck.

Regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This simply seems to be unsupported

I couldn't even make the magic happen with `boost::assign::ptr_map_insert`¹

I suggest making a function that builds the map and then just returning a const copy or reference to it:

```
ptr_map<A,V> const m = make_my_map();
```

---

¹ In case you're interested:

```
#include <boost/ptr_container/ptr_map.hpp>
#include <boost/assign/ptr_map_inserter.hpp>

struct A {
    int i;
    A(int i):i(i) {}
    bool operator<(A const& other) const { return i<other.i; }
};
struct B { std::string s;
    B(std::string s) : s(std::move(s)) { }
};

int main() {
    boost::ptr_map<A, /*const*/ B> m;

    boost::assign::ptr_map_insert(m)(42, "forty-two");
}
```